# Is it possible to take the Root Mean Square Error of a continuous function?

Tags: goodness-of-fit, error, continuous-data

I am familiar with the Root Mean Square Error (RMSE) of discrete data: $$\text{RMSE} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i = i}^N |{\hat{y_i} - y_i}|^2}$$ where $\hat{y_i}$ are "predicted" or measured observations, $y_i$ are the true values, and $N$ is the number of observations. My question is, **can we extend this definition for *continuous* data, i.e. observations as given by continuous functions?**

My reasoning is that we can, since we can generalize the summation as an integral, and as we consider infinitely many data points, $N \to \infty,$ so that if we define $\delta x \equiv 1/N$, $\delta x \to dx$ in the new limit. Thus, $$\text{RMSE} = \sqrt{\int_{a}^b |\hat{f(x)} - f(x)|^2 \, dx}$$ where the limits of integration correspond to, say, the beginning and the end of the dataset. Is this argument valid? I'm pretty sure there must exist some kind of error-estimation methods for continuous functions, but I am not familiar with them. Is this the same as evaluating "goodness of fit"?

Comment: What would constitute the (uncountably infinite??) dataset to which this integral appears to refer?  Understanding this would help us appreciate what your question might be.

Answer (score 1):

What you have in mind is probably the [Cramér–von Mises criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93von_Mises_criterion) for goodness of fit:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} [F_n(x)-F^*(x)]^2\,\mathrm{d}F^*(x)$$

where $F^{*}$ is the theoretical *cumulative* distribution and
$F_{n}$ is the empirically observed distribution.

Your argument from the discrete RMSE implicitly weights all observations the same. Your extension to the continuous case effectively weights all values of $x$ between $a$ and $b$ the same. The Cramér–von Mises criterion evaluates the mean squared distance over the theoretical distribution $F^{*}$, which is what is of primary interest. That is, it answers the question: if I sample from $F^{*}(x)$ (rather than from $x$) how large is the mean-square difference between the observed and the theoretical distribution.